# Kryo on Android: Could not find class 'sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer'

Tags: android, kryo, kryonet

I use Kryonet on Android, and after start up, the VM crashes with this error:
Could not find class 'sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer', referenced from method com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.UnsafeUtil.releaseBuffer.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That class is part of java, but not Android.  Android doesn't support the sun.nio.* classes.  So the library isn't android compatible.